# Python construction of value set dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

.I've been dealing with list comprehension recently, I came across a problem I can't seem to solve>

let's say I have pairs in the form of:
A,B,C,X="ABCX"
   init = {(A,B),(B,C),(C,X)}

I am trying to construct a dictionary, where each key would be an individual letter, and each value all connections this letter has with other, so>

```
{A:{B},B:{A,C},C:{B,X},X:{C}}
```

Things I tried>

```
final_dict = {k : {j for p,j in init if p==k} for k,v in init}
```

but  this returns me ony if the partner is located in the second place,

Trying to add the first place>

```
final_dict = {k : {j for p,j in init if p==k or p if j == k} for k,v in init}
```

An error occurs.

Comment: Is it possible for multiples of the same letter? Also this isn't a nested dictionary, it a dict with strings as keys and sets as values.

Comment: No, no multiples, I will correct the description thanks

Comment: Does the solution have to be a dict comprehension?

Comment: Preferably yes, but if no it is also OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution without dict comp

```
init = {('A','B'),('B','C'),('C','X')}

d = {}
for k, v in init:
    d.setdefault(k, set()).add(v)
    d.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)
```

The problem is that with your current format for the data you can't properly specify the key, values. Ideally it should be.

```
init = {('A','B'),('B','A'),('B','C'),('C','B'),('C','X'),('X','C')}
```

Which you can obtain by doing the following if you don't want to / can't adjust your current method for getting the pairs.

```
init2 = {(y, x) for x, y in init}.union(init)
```

So you can then do

```
d = { key : { v for k, v in init2 if k == key } for key, _ in init2 }
```

There is also this, but it doesn't include X, and again it would probably become much larger to make work due to the current format.

```
d = { k : {v1 if k == v2 else v for v1, v2 in init } for k, v in init }
```