# List of tuple pairs into dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I am having trouble with dictionaries in Python. I realise the task is very simple, yet I can't figure it out. My task is to write a function, which converts a list of tuples into a dictionary, where the keys of the dictionary represent the people (from the tuples) and the values represent their friends. Per exp:

```
pairs_of_people = {("Adam", "Brian"), ("Adam", "Gabe"), ("Adam", "Hagan"),
    ("Brian", "Calvin"), ("Brian", "Hagan"),
    ("Calvin", "Dan")}`
```

must return:

```
{"Adam": {"Brian", "Gabe", "Hagan"}, "Brian": {"Adam", "Hagan", "Calvin"}, "Calvin": {"Brian", "Dan"}}
```

Any help? Thank you. An if someone has a good intro on dictionaries somewhere, it would be greatly appreciated. I just can't figure them out.

Comment: FYI the values in your desired output are sets, not dictionaries. Easy to confuse the two if you are new to dictionaries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python construction of value set dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690537/python-construction-of-value-set-dictionary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very quick way to brute force this solution is to use a defaultdict.
This will add to our output dictionary the people and their friends if either the "person" or the "friend" is a required key (the first person in the input tuples).

```
from collections import defaultdict

pairs_of_people = {("Adam", "Brian"), ("Adam", "Gabe"), ("Adam", "Hagan"),
               ("Brian", "Calvin"), ("Brian", "Hagan"),
               ("Calvin", "Dan")}

required_keys = {t[0] for t in pairs_of_people}

out = defaultdict(set)

for person, friend in pairs_of_people:
    if person in required_keys:
        out[person].add(friend)
    if friend in required_keys:
        out[friend].add(person)

print(out)
>> {"Adam": {"Brian", "Gabe", "Hagan"}, "Brian": {"Adam", "Hagan", "Calvin"},
    "Calvin": {"Brian", "Dan"}}
```

Comment: Yep, this one worked & is actually a bit easier to understand than the first example mentioned above. Thank you. :)

Comment: One more question. How would I do the exact reverse? In other words, how would I transform this new dictionary back into pairs of people?

Comment: @KevinKlarić The reverse is actually easier: `friendships = {"Adam": {"Brian", "Gabe", "Hagan"}, "Brian": {"Adam", "Hagan", "Calvin"},
    "Calvin": {"Brian", "Dan"}}  ;  

li = []   ; 
for person, friends in friendships.items():
    for friend in friends:
        li.append((person, friend))`

Comment: One more problem. While your solution does work, it returns more than I have to return (for the task at hand). For example, converting this {"A": {"B"}, "B": {"A"}}) to pairs should return only this pair {("A", "B")} and not both A, B and B, A.

Another example:
This {A: {B, C}, B: {A, C}, C: {A, B, D}, D: {C}} should return:
{(A, B), (A, C), (B, C), (C, D)}

Answer (score 2):

It is way easier to construct this dict containing `sets` (apparently) by using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a `set` as the default factory:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set)
```

Also, use an auxiliary `set` of `names` containing the first name from each tuple. That way you can check for membership and, if two pairs are names in the `names` set they'll be added to each others resulting sets:

```
names = {i[0] for i in pairs_of_people}

for i, j in pairs_of_people:
    d[i].add(j)
    if j in names:
        d[j].add(i)

d = dict(d)   # if necessarily a dict
```

A `defaultdict` is just a special kind of dict that makes these tasks less tedious. Now, `d` contains:

```
print(d)
{'Brian': {'Hagan', 'Adam', 'Calvin'}, 'Adam': {'Hagan', 'Brian', 'Gabe'}, 'Calvin': {'Brian', 'Dan'}}
```

Due to the fact that your tuples are contained in a set, you can't have predetermined ordering unless you move them to a list and then sort them. You could also change `defaultdict` to have a default factory of list with `d = defaultdict(list)` and use `d[i].append(j)` and `d[j].append(i)` instead of `.add`.

As for an introduction to dictionaries, you could look into the section on Dictionaries of the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: This is good, but my output has to have the exact same order as the one I wrote above.

Comment: @KevinKlarić sets don't have ordering and neither do dictionaries, the ordering might be different on different runs of Python.